# Magento 2 can't login admin page after migration from local server (XAMPP)

Tags: magento2

I need urgent help as to how to log into my admin page. Everything is working fine after migration but admin page refuses to log me in. I have tried so many suggestions here. But not is working for me. I use Magento V2.2.3

Comment: any error in logs? what is the error message you are getting during login?

Comment: No error log or message. It  just rolls and stops with cleared form values.. basically just refreshes.

Comment: is there any cookie domain set in configuration?

Comment: try different browser , there would be cookies issue.

Comment: it was configured on xampp and migrated... i don't know much about magento as i am new to it

Comment: Please check base and secure url in database `core_config_data` table.

Comment: unscure i used domain without https and for secure i used https... And i noticed when i views the website over https: it tells me it is secure. But when i visit the admin panel with https, it redirects to an umsecure login page.

Comment: After RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] 
I tried this:::
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: Till now set HTTP instead of https. and also work in private browser for some time. and which error occurred when you log in to the admin panel?

Comment: Okay it works in a Private Browser when i used http for admin

Comment: If it is really useful then upvote it. so people can easily find right solution.

Answer (score 1):

Directly in database, Edit `web/secure/base_url` in `core_config_data` table.

Please set HTTP instead of https.

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I opened app/etc/env.php file and changed the name of the shop backend .

'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'new_admin_backend_name'
    ]

Should clear up anything related to the old backend name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a cookie domain set to the new host name.

I managed to correct this with the following steps on database level:

```
UPDATE core_config_data
SET value='new-domain.example.com'
WHERE path = 'web/cookie/cookie_domain';
```

And then it worked! Thanks for the hint @Kalyan Chakravarthi V

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following `path` in the `core_config_data` table. They should have the correct URL.

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
web/unsecure/base_link_url
web/secure/base_link_url
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my base urls with:
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://new_url/"
then cleared cache with php bin/magento cache:flush

I tried to log in to admin but no success. Then I tried to change web/secure/base_url to http manually in the database but this did not had any effect also.

What helped in the end was the answer from Bradley saying to change app/etc/env.php file and change the name of your admin url. I was then able to log in to backend.

'backend' => [ 'frontName' => 'new_admin_backend_name' ]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/199579)